# Show that at least one of $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ must be the constant solution at the origin.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $A$ be an invertible $3\times3$ matrix, and consider the equation
> $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$   Suppose there are three solutions
> $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ with the properties:
>
> 1. $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$
> 2. $\lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}y(t)=0$
> 3. $z(4\pi)=z(0)$
>
> Show that at least one of $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ must be the constant
> solution at the origin.

**My Attempt:**
I first thought about this as a problem that should involve the stable manifold theorem, but later realized, that you need the flow $\phi_{t}(x)$ for that. But given here is just a solution.

And then I thought of coming up with an answer by simple manipulation of limits, like $z(0)=z(\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t))=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}z(x(t))...$  But it was also not helpful.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Note that $z$ is $4\pi$-periodic because the solution $z(4\pi+t)-z(t)$ vanishes at $t=0$, hence for all $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** The solution $z$ is necessarily $4\pi$-periodic. Let us suppose that $z$ is not constant. Let $P\subset \bf{R}^3$ be the subspace of initial conditions at $t=0$ that generate $4\pi$-periodic solutions. As $z(0)\in P$, we know that $\dim(P)\ge 1$, but the derivative of a $4\pi$-periodic solution is also $4\pi$-periodic, which implies that $u\in P\Longrightarrow A u\in P$, in other terms, $P$ is stable by $A$. If we had $\dim(P)=1$, it would imply that $A z(0) = \lambda z(0)$, hence $z(t) = e^{\lambda t}z(0)$, hence $\lambda=0$ by periodicity which is impossible because $z$ would be constant.

It follows that $\dim(P)\ge 2$, now let $\lambda$ be a real eigenvalue of $A$ (there is at least one) and $V_\lambda$ its (stable) eigenspace. If $\lambda\neq 0$ one must have ${\bf R}^3=P\oplus V_\lambda$. By decomposing $x(0)$ and $y(0)$ on this space decomposition, one gets that if they are not zero, $\lambda$ must be simultaneously negative and posivive, a contradiction. If $\lambda=0$, then $P={\bf R}^3$, but then $x$ and $y$ must be $0$ because they are periodic and tend to $0$.

**Alternate strategy**
Assume that $z$ is not constant

- If $z, z', z''$ are independent, then all the solutions are $4\pi$-periodic and $x$ and $y$ must vanish.
- Otherwise, $W=\text{span}(z(0), z'(0))$ is a 2 dimensional subspace of ${\bf R}^3$, stable by $A$, containing no eigenvector of $A$.
- Write ${\bf R}^3 = W\oplus V_\lambda$ and conclude as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. But I think I'm missing a certain theory part. Can you please mention why $u\in P \Rightarrow Au\in P$ implies that $P$ is stable. Is that an equivalent definition?

Comment: If $z(t)$ is a solution and $4\pi$-periodic, it means that $u = z(0)\in P$ but $z'(t)$ is also a $4\pi$-periodic solution because $z''(t) = A z'(t)$. Hence $z'(0)\in P$, but $z'(0) = A z(0)= A u$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help